# Image size in Magnific Popup

Tags: css, image, popup, size

Is there any way to influence the size of the image displayed? In other words: Can I achieve the same size for the full image even if the original pictures have different sizes?

Many thanks
Michael

The Q&A "found the answer. It can be done by changing the respective class's css properties manually. But, that is also fixed for all images." states like this. Which css property has to be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make the image bigger? Not recommended as this will most likely compromise image quality, but you can give it a width over 100% and a height of auto. Want to make it smaller? Give it a max-width less than 100% and height: auto. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Magnific Popup is called from DJ ImageSlider containing images in different formats. The goal is to display all full images in Magnific Popup with a certain fixed size even if I loose image quality. Thanks-Michael

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, if my answer helped at all or is the solution to your problem, feel free to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 10):

This solution makes all images appear in full height. If it is higher than the viewport you'll have to scroll to see it completely.

Also, it never exceeds the image dimensions. It simply allows you to see it on the original size

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
            jQuery('.trigger').magnificPopup({
                type: 'image',  
                callbacks: {
                    resize: changeImgSize,
                    imageLoadComplete:changeImgSize,
                    change:changeImgSize
                }
            });
        });
        function changeImgSize(){
            var img = this.content.find('img');
            img.css('max-height', '100%');
            img.css('width', 'auto');
            img.css('max-width', 'auto');
        }
```

Comment: I did this, but instead of using the JS callbacks, I applied those styles to `.mfp-content, .mfp-img` using `!important`